# How to deal with multiple ListenableFutures? (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I am writing a controller, that I need to make it asynchronous. How can I deal with a list of `ListenableFuture`? Because I have a list of URLs that I need to send GET request one by one, what is the best solution for it?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/repositories", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    private void getUsername(@RequestParam(value = "username") String username) {
        System.out.println(username);
        List<ListenableFuture> futureList = githubRestAsync.getRepositoryLanguages(username);
        System.out.println(futureList.size());
}
```

In the service I use `List<ListanbleFuture>` which seems does not work, since it is asynchronous, in the controller method I cannot have the size of `futureList` to run a `for loop` on it for the callbacks.

```
public List<ListenableFuture> getRepositoryLanguages(String username){
      return getRepositoryLanguages(username, getUserRepositoriesFuture(username));
    }

private ListenableFuture getUserRepositoriesFuture(String username) throws HttpClientErrorException {
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(httpHeaders);
        ListenableFuture future = restTemplate.exchange(githubUsersUrl + username + "/repos", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
        return future;
    }
private List<ListenableFuture> getRepositoryLanguages(final String username, ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> future) {
        final List<ListenableFuture> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<String> response) {
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                try {
                    repositories = mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), new TypeReference<List<Repositories>>() {
                    });
                    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(httpHeaders);
                    System.out.println("Repo size: " + repositories.size());
                    for (int i = 0; i < repositories.size(); i++) {
                        futures.add(restTemplate.exchange(githubReposUrl + username + "/" + repositories.get(i).getName() + "/languages", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                System.out.println("FAILURE in getRepositoryLanguages: " + throwable.getMessage());
            }
        });

        return futures;
    }
```

Should I use something like `ListenableFuture<List>` instead of `List<ListenableFuture>` ?

Comment: What did you end up doing? I actually need to make a large number of REST calls to a 3rd party service from my own REST application, so I am trying to figure out what pattern to follow. My REST application is built using Spring Boot 1.4.3 and Java 8.

Comment: I wonder what is the desired outcome here? sending GET requests "one by one" does not sound like async to me.

Comment: My problem is similar where I need to make a number of http requests and then process their answer before returning. My approach is to fire all the requests asynchronously rather than in sequence. I was wondering what the best approach to go about doing this, as from what I understand `ListenableFuture` is per request, you can say wait for all requests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you have a `List<ListenableFuture<Result>>`, but you want a `ListenableFuture<List<Result>>`, so you can take one action when all of the futures are complete.

```
public static <T> ListenableFuture<List<T>> allOf(final List<? extends ListenableFuture<? extends T>> futures) {
    // we will return this ListenableFuture, and modify it from within callbacks on each input future
    final SettableListenableFuture<List<T>> groupFuture = new SettableListenableFuture<>();

    // use a defensive shallow copy of the futures list, to avoid errors that could be caused by
    // someone inserting/removing a future from `futures` list after they call this method
    final List<? extends ListenableFuture<? extends T>> futuresCopy = new ArrayList<>(futures);

    // Count the number of completed futures with an AtomicInt (to avoid race conditions)
    final AtomicInteger resultCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < futuresCopy.size(); i++) {
        futuresCopy.get(i).addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<T>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final T result) {
                int thisCount = resultCount.incrementAndGet();

                // if this is the last result, build the ArrayList and complete the GroupFuture
                if (thisCount == futuresCopy.size()) {
                   List<T> resultList = new ArrayList<T>(futuresCopy.size());
                    try {
                        for (ListenableFuture<? extends T> future : futuresCopy) {
                            resultList.add(future.get());
                        }
                        groupFuture.set(resultList);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // this should never happen, but future.get() forces us to deal with this exception.
                        groupFuture.setException(e);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(final Throwable throwable) {
                groupFuture.setException(throwable);

                // if one future fails, don't waste effort on the others
                for (ListenableFuture future : futuresCopy) {
                    future.cancel(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    return groupFuture;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Im not quite sure if you are starting a new project or working on a legacy one, but if the main requirement for you is none blocking and asynchronous rest service I would suggest you to have a look into upcoming Spring Framework 5 and it integration with [reactive streams](https://spring.io/blog/2016/07/28/reactive-programming-with-spring-5-0-m1). Particularly Spring 5 will allow you to create fully reactive and asynchronous web services with little of coding.

So for example fully functional version of your code can be written with this small code snippet.

```
@RestController
public class ReactiveController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/repositories")
    public Flux<String> getUsername(@RequestParam(value = "username") String username) {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create(new ReactorClientHttpConnector());
        ClientRequest<Void> listRepoRequest = ClientRequest.GET("https://api.github.com/users/{username}/repos", username)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("user-agent", "reactive.java").build();

        return client.exchange(listRepoRequest).flatMap(response -> response.bodyToFlux(Repository.class)).flatMap(
            repository -> client
                    .exchange(ClientRequest
                            .GET("https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{repo}/languages", username,
                                    repository.getName())
                            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("user-agent", "reactive.java").build())
                    .map(r -> r.bodyToMono(String.class)))
            .concatMap(Flux::merge);
    }

    static class Repository {
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

}
```

To run this code locally just clone the [spring-boot-starter-web-reactive](https://github.com/bclozel/spring-boot-web-reactive) and copy the code into it.

The result is something like `{"Java":50563,"JavaScript":11541,"CSS":1177}{"Java":50469}{"Java":130182}{"Shell":21222,"Makefile":7169,"JavaScript":1156}{"Java":30754,"Shell":7058,"JavaScript":5486,"Batchfile":5006,"HTML":4865}` still you can map it to something more usable in asynchronous way :)

Comment: I will definitely look into Spring 5 :) but in this example the second GET still happens after the first one, rather than at the same time, right?

Comment: Yes, after the first one,  as there is no way you can execute them both at the same time, as second execution depends on the first one )) so logic requires data from first GET to start the second one ...  But the reactive way of handling things will not block your processor while waiting the data from the first GET ...